# Pandas Dataframe Boolean to row number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, row

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
column = (dataframe.select_dtypes(include=['integer'])) >= 2
print(column)
```

This returns a DataFrame of row numbers and `True` `False` Booleans.

How do I return the row numbers of the True Booleans such that I can pass them back to print the name(string) in another column of the DataFrame?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful to see what your data looks like, could you provide a reproducible (not an image) subset of it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any sample data or expected output.  The following will give you the rows in the dataframe where all the integer columns in the row are >= 2

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":["a","b","c","d"]})
df[(df.select_dtypes(include='integer')>=2).all(axis=1)]
```

### output

```
    a   b
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
```